# Access VBA SQL query searching between dates

Tags: sql, vba

I have a some VBA code that takes in a date from and date to fields from two date picker values in textboxes.

However, when searching between the two dates I receive the 'Enter Parameter Value' prompt asking for input.

```
Dim SQLAllReject As String

Dim strDateFrom As String
Dim strDateTo As String

strDateFrom = Format(txtDate.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
strDateTo = Format(txtDateTo.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

When running directly in the Query Design wizard, searching between dates works fine:

```
WHERE (((XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Date) Between #10/1/2021# And #10/27/2021#))
```

What is wrong here? How can I force Access/VBA to take the dates I've specified and search between them and NOT display the 'Enter Parameter Value' prompt?

When I debug the query and step through, it gives exactly the same dates as running it in Query Design view.

FYI if I use one date and the LIKE operator, this works fine.

```
SQLAllReject = "SELECT dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.HashKey AS [ID], dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.Reject_Date AS [Date], " & _
    "FROM dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy " & _
    "WHERE (((dbo_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.Reject_Date) Between #" & strDateFrom & "# And #" & strDateTo & "#)) " & _
    "ORDER BY dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.Reject_Date DESC;"
```

Comment: You declarate variables as string type. You need convert string to date type.

Comment: How does your sql string looks like - the one where you use strDateFrom?

Comment: SQLAllReject = "SELECT dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.HashKey AS [ID], dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.Reject_Date AS [Date], " & _
 "FROM dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy " & _
 "WHERE (((dbo_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.Reject_Date) Between #" & strDateFrom & "# And #" & strDateTo & "#)) " & _
 "ORDER BY dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.Reject_Date DESC;"

Comment: if you use Debug.Print strDateFrom and Debug.Print strDateTo are your outputs expected and in the correct format as your db?

Comment: You have an extra comma `dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy.Reject_Date AS [Date],`. Date shouldn't have a trailing comma, you aren't selecting any more fields.

Comment: For the sake of readability: do you know that you can use an _alias_ for your table like: `SELECT t.x FROM table_with_very_long_name t WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I somehow fixed it... the query string was trying to select from a view rather than the table and for some odd reason it was causing the parameter prompt.

I have changed dbo_vw_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy to dbo_busobj_file_rejections_load_access_temp5_copy table and managed to get it to work after doing some string to date conversion when selecting dates from the textboxes.